# Extjs how submit form without ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4, form-submit

Good day!
I am try submit extjs form without ajax and show result on the next page. This is my code:

```
Ext.define('test.from', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.test.form',
    initComponent: function () {

        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(this, {
            frame: true,
            bodyPadding: 7,
            border: 0,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                name: 'contact_attr'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                name: 'contact_attr'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Send',
                handler: function () {
                    me.getForm().submit({
                        url: '/salary/public/auth/',
                        standardSubmit: true,
                        method: 'POST'
                    });
                }
            }]
        });
```

But redirect to other page doesn't occur and I receive error: `You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String`. Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Comment: maybe post that invalid json, and the code that produced it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, so you have 2 error.

1. why not redirect(standarssubmit), and
2. why you got "error decode"

i guess you're using extjs4:

1 . From the docs api. it say that `submit()` method is `Shortcut to do a submit action`. and the parameter is `The options to pass to the action (see doAction for details)`. so, putting `standardSubmit` to `submit` method isn't the correct way. there is no standardSubmit option. [more info](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-doAction). myanswer, you have 2 alternative way.
first, use the init:

```
Ext.apply(this,{
    standardSubmit:true,  // not working...
    frame: true,
    bodyPadding: 7,
    .......
```

---

Edits:

```
.......
me.getForm().standardSubmit=true; //just like OP comment
me.getForm().submit({
   url: '/salary/public/auth/',
   standardSubmit: true,
   method: 'POST'
});
.......
```

---

second, use doAction:

```
...
me.getForm().doAction('standardsubmit',{
   url: '/salary/public/auth/',
   standardSubmit: true,
   method: 'POST'
});
...
```

2 . the error decode, i don't know what is your `salary/public/auth` look like....
try my first solution, if error exists, it mean the error is somewhere else...

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answer! Your first solution don't work, but second solution works well. Yesterday I also found the decision:   `var form = me.getForm();  
              form.url = '/salary/public/auth';  
              form.standardSubmit = true;  
              form.method = 'POST';  
              form.submit();`  Thank you for help!

Comment: Use standardSubmit as a config of the form panel, don't apply it to the basic form or action.